# ADC bit interpretation in programming languages in terms of data type

Tags: adc, fpga

I was working with a board that had an ADC that interfaces with an FPGA and I was curious as to the data type a programming language that receives the bits from the ADC would interpret it as.

For simplicity, assume it's an 16-bit ADC and the voltage range is 0-1V. I can of course find the resolution etc. and I will have an idea of what the bits will look like, but I am not sure how to interpret this in a high level programming language like C. Would I interpret the bits as int type or float type?

Let's say I interpret them as int type. What if I needed to perform floating point calculations on the data? Would I do said calculations as if it were a float then round to the nearest integer before say passing it on to the DAC?

If I interpret them as float then I also fear that I would be losing some data or better yet some accuracy.

I don't really have any analogies to help me visualize the issue better so any pointers (no pun intended) would be gladly welcomed.

Comment: if on an mcu you want to avoid float as much as possible obviously and often float is not needed.  the datasheets should/will indicate what the data is, signed or unsigned maybe it is not full range maybe 16000 to -16000 or some such scheme (I have seen things like this to get things into a power of ten, going beyond that upper and lower indicating an error) ....  more importantly though is the interface(s) between this high level language code and the adc itself.   and as you work through that/those communication paths, you can look at the raw values so that by the time you are ...

Comment: writing high level language code to operate on the data, you have confirmed the adc documentation and know exactly how to handle that data.   Now understanding you probably do not want to just use a (signed) short for example or int16, you probably want to use something natively larger (32 or 64 bit int) and take the raw data and adjust and sign extend as needed to fit into the variable type you want to use...

Comment: for example it if is bipolar/signed then you could add an offset and make it unipolar/unsigned, all depending on the signal and the math of interest.

Comment: I’d use fixed point (integer) math, but if you want to use floating point you’re not losing any precision. 32 bit (single precision) floats have a mantissa of 24 bits, so they can represent all 16 bit integers no problem

Comment: Everything is being used out there, even just raw adc values...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I am not sure how to interpret this in a high level programming language like C. Would I interpret the bits as int type or float type?

This is really a question for the API documentation on your ADC. Internally 16 bit ADCs will return integers, but the signedness can vary. I have also seen drivers that convert types on data, so just because the hardware uses a certain format doesn't mean that is what you will receive in a higher level language.

> Let's say I interpret them as int type. what if I needed to perform floating point calculations on the data. Would I do said calculations as if it were a float then round to the nearest integer before say passing it on to the DAC.

You have to "interpret" them as what they actually are or the data will be corrupted. However, nothing stops you can converting integers to floating point if that's what you want to work with.

Comment: In addition it's very common to read an ADC as (say) 12 significant bits into a 16-bit integer discarding the top four, then to repeat n times and scale into either a larger integer type or a float. Depending on the language, that immediately raises questions relating to whether you can both mask (i.e. a bitwise AND) and perform arithmetic operations on the selected type.

Comment: I took a look at the datasheet for the ADC and there were 2 options for the data interpretation. The first is offset binary and the second 2s complement. I checked how the board was connected and it seems that it’s on the offset binary setting. Honestly, going to have to read what that means for me but maybe I could convert it from the offset binary to a fixed precision representation (for DSP purposes) but I’ll have to think about it I suppose. 

I wouldn’t have checked the Documentation were it not for your suggestion so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the application.

Many embedded control applications treat ADC values as integers for simplicity and efficiency.

But signal-processing applications (e.g., audio or video) tend to handle the sample values as fixed-point fractional numbers, usually with a span of 0 to 1 or -1 to 1. The advantage of this is that if you add bits for more resolution, the math doesn't change in terms of scaling the numbers. DSP chips tend to have support for this representation, but of course, it is not common in high-level programming languages.

Once samples are converted to real-world values (such as actual voltages or currents, or sensor readings such as acceleration or rotation rate), they're often handled as floating point numbers, along with the correct units.

Comment: Audio DSP strongly benefits from using floating point. (Both because human hearing is logarithmic, and for maths reasons.) Any decent software implementations use floats pretty much throughout the entire signal chain. Not quite sure how it is in the hardware realm, but at least for professional applications I would be very surprised if they only used fixed-point.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Historically, many DSPs designed for audio use had fixed-point math units, and using floating-point resulted in horrible performance.  To get good performance, one must select data formats and algorithms that are a good fit for the hardware.  On some platforms, an algorithm that uses 100 `double` multiplies and 200 `double` additions might be more than twice as fast as one which requires 300 `float` multiplies and 400 `float` additions, but on others the reverse might be true.

Comment: I actually want to use fixed point for DSP purposes (as floating point is too costly in terms of time) but for my algorithm to actually work I’ll need to get the data to a fixed point representation without losing anything and as things stand with the ADC values being in offset binary (just found out) going to be a lot of thinking :)